# AWS Cloudformation CIDR block conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, cidr

I am currently trying to wrap my head around how to use AWS CloudFormation service. This might be a really simple question, but I think it is very hard to understand the platform so far.
I followed Amazon's tutorial on how to create a basic web server. Going off the final template from there, I want to modify it to enable a user-defined VPC IP range. For this, I tried to add a VPC CIDR Block property, as well as modify the PublicSubnet settings to get a /24 subnet from the block property, but when trying to create a stack I get the following error message:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdaVq.png]

Here's the template I am trying to use:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template VPC_Single_Instance_In_Subnet: Sample template showing how to create a VPC and add an EC2 instance with an Elastic IP address and a security group. **WARNING** This template creates an Amazon EC2 instance. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template.",
    "Parameters": {
        "InstanceType": {
            "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "t2.micro",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "t1.micro",
                "t2.micro",
                "t2.small",
                "t2.medium"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance.",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
        },
        "SSHLocation": {
            "Description": " The IP address range that can be used access the web server using SSH.",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "9",
            "MaxLength": "18",
            "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
        }
    },
    "Mappings": {
        "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
            "t1.micro": {"Arch": "PV64"},
            "t2.micro": {"Arch": "HVM64"},
            "t2.small": {"Arch": "HVM64"},
            "t2.medium": {"Arch": "HVM64"}
        },
        "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
            "us-east-1": {
                "PV64": "ami-1ccae774",
                "HVM64": "ami-1ecae776",
                "HVMG2": "ami-8c6b40e4"
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
                "EnableDnsHostnames": "true",
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16"
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee"}
            }
        },
        "VpcCidrBlock": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16"
            }
        },
        "PublicSubnet": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": { "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Fn::Cidr" : ["10.0.0.0/24", 1, 8 ]}]},
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3"}
            }
        },
        "InternetGateway": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63"}
            }
        },
        "VPCGatewayAttachment": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
                "InternetGatewayId": {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "1790ebeb-2e41-4293-8cc1-aaba134fd1e0"}
            }
        },
        "PublicRouteTable": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d"}
            }
        },
        "PublicRoute": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "DependsOn": "VPCGatewayAttachment",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "PublicRouteTable"},
                "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "GatewayId": {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "143bbaa1-66a2-42a5-885f-e6300817103c"}
            }
        },
        "PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "SubnetId": {"Ref": "PublicSubnet"},
                "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "PublicRouteTable"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "528e2b71-46e6-4e09-815a-f70630755219"}
            }
        },
        "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
                "GroupDescription": "Allow access from HTTP and SSH traffic",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "ToPort": "80",
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": {"Ref": "SSHLocation"}
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "2e76192b-a4f8-48a5-92b6-abbfa8b83263"}
            }
        },
        "WebServerInstance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                    "configSets": {
                        "All": ["ConfigureSampleApp"]
                    },
                    "ConfigureSampleApp": {
                        "packages": {
                            "yum": {
                                "httpd": []
                            }
                        },
                        "files": {
                            "/var/www/html/index.html": {
                                "content": {
                                    "Fn::Join": [
                                        "\n",
                                        ["<h1>Congratulations, you have successfully launched the AWS CloudFormation sample.</h1>"]
                                    ]
                                },
                                "mode": "000644",
                                "owner": "root",
                                "group": "root"
                            }
                        },
                        "services": {
                            "sysvinit": {
                                "httpd": {
                                    "enabled": "true",
                                    "ensureRunning": "true"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "0f900c9e-1272-4ec2-8a42-790b074baa39"}
            },
            "Properties": {
                "InstanceType": {"Ref": "InstanceType"},
                "ImageId": {
                    "Fn::FindInMap": [
                        "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                        {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                        {
                            "Fn::FindInMap": [
                                "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                                {"Ref": "InstanceType"},
                                "Arch"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyName"},
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "GroupSet": [
                            {"Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}
                        ],
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
                        "DeviceIndex": "0",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                        "SubnetId": {"Ref": "PublicSubnet"}
                    }
                ],
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                                "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                                "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
                                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                                "         --stack ",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},
                                "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                                "         --configsets All ",
                                "         --region ",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                                "\n",
                                "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                                "         --stack ",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},
                                "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                                "         --region ",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                                "\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "CreationPolicy": {
                "ResourceSignal": {"Timeout": "PT5M"}
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "URL": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "http://",
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "WebServerInstance",
                                "PublicIp"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "Description": "Newly created application URL"
        },
        "SubnetCIDR": {
            "Value": {"Ref": "PublicSubnet"},
            "Description": "Subnet for the application"
        }
    },
    "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": -40,
                    "y": 210
                },
                "z": 1,
                "embeds": []
            },
            "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 250
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 70,
                    "y": 190
                },
                "z": 1,
                "embeds": [
                    "2e76192b-a4f8-48a5-92b6-abbfa8b83263",
                    "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d"
                ]
            },
            "2e76192b-a4f8-48a5-92b6-abbfa8b83263": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 280,
                    "y": 370
                },
                "z": 2,
                "parent": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee",
                "embeds": []
            },
            "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 120
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 90,
                    "y": 230
                },
                "z": 2,
                "parent": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee",
                "embeds": ["143bbaa1-66a2-42a5-885f-e6300817103c"]
            },
            "1790ebeb-2e41-4293-8cc1-aaba134fd1e0": {
                "source": {"id": "a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63"},
                "target": {"id": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee"},
                "z": 1
            },
            "143bbaa1-66a2-42a5-885f-e6300817103c": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 120,
                    "y": 260
                },
                "z": 3,
                "parent": "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d",
                "embeds": [],
                "references": ["a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63"],
                "dependson": ["1790ebeb-2e41-4293-8cc1-aaba134fd1e0"],
                "isrelatedto": ["a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63"]
            },
            "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 120
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 250,
                    "y": 230
                },
                "z": 0,
                "embeds": ["0f900c9e-1272-4ec2-8a42-790b074baa39"]
            },
            "0f900c9e-1272-4ec2-8a42-790b074baa39": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 280,
                    "y": 260
                },
                "z": 3,
                "parent": "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3",
                "embeds": [],
                "isrelatedto": ["2e76192b-a4f8-48a5-92b6-abbfa8b83263"]
            },
            "13e0e0da-40c9-45d0-8460-7732ed20d764": {
                "source": {"id": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee"},
                "target": {"id": "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3"},
                "z": 2
            },
            "528e2b71-46e6-4e09-815a-f70630755219": {
                "source": {"id": "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d"},
                "target": {"id": "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3"},
                "z": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock`. Instead you add `VPCCidr` parameter to your template and use that:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template VPC_Single_Instance_In_Subnet: Sample template showing how to create a VPC and add an EC2 instance with an Elastic IP address and a security group. **WARNING** This template creates an Amazon EC2 instance. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template.",
    "Parameters": {
        "InstanceType": {
            "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "t2.micro",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "t1.micro",
                "t2.micro",
                "t2.small",
                "t2.medium"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
        },
        "KeyName": {
            "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance.",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
        },
        "VPCCidr": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "10.0.0.0/16"
        },
        "SSHLocation": {
            "Description": " The IP address range that can be used access the web server using SSH.",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "9",
            "MaxLength": "18",
            "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
        }
    },
    "Mappings": {
        "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
            "t1.micro": {"Arch": "PV64"},
            "t2.micro": {"Arch": "HVM64"},
            "t2.small": {"Arch": "HVM64"},
            "t2.medium": {"Arch": "HVM64"}
        },
        "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
            "us-east-1": {
                "PV64": "ami-1ccae774",
                "HVM64": "ami-1ecae776",
                "HVMG2": "ami-8c6b40e4"
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
                "EnableDnsHostnames": "true",
                "CidrBlock": {"Ref": "VPCCidr"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee"}
            }
        },
        "PublicSubnet": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": { "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Fn::Cidr" : [{"Ref": "VPCCidr"}, 1, 8 ]}]},
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3"}
            }
        },
        "InternetGateway": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway",
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63"}
            }
        },
        "VPCGatewayAttachment": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
                "InternetGatewayId": {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "1790ebeb-2e41-4293-8cc1-aaba134fd1e0"}
            }
        },
        "PublicRouteTable": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::RouteTable",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d"}
            }
        },
        "PublicRoute": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Route",
            "DependsOn": "VPCGatewayAttachment",
            "Properties": {
                "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "PublicRouteTable"},
                "DestinationCidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "GatewayId": {"Ref": "InternetGateway"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "143bbaa1-66a2-42a5-885f-e6300817103c"}
            }
        },
        "PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation",
            "Properties": {
                "SubnetId": {"Ref": "PublicSubnet"},
                "RouteTableId": {"Ref": "PublicRouteTable"}
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "528e2b71-46e6-4e09-815a-f70630755219"}
            }
        },
        "WebServerSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
                "GroupDescription": "Allow access from HTTP and SSH traffic",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "ToPort": "80",
                        "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": {"Ref": "SSHLocation"}
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "2e76192b-a4f8-48a5-92b6-abbfa8b83263"}
            }
        },
        "WebServerInstance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                    "configSets": {
                        "All": ["ConfigureSampleApp"]
                    },
                    "ConfigureSampleApp": {
                        "packages": {
                            "yum": {
                                "httpd": []
                            }
                        },
                        "files": {
                            "/var/www/html/index.html": {
                                "content": {
                                    "Fn::Join": [
                                        "\n",
                                        ["<h1>Congratulations, you have successfully launched the AWS CloudFormation sample.</h1>"]
                                    ]
                                },
                                "mode": "000644",
                                "owner": "root",
                                "group": "root"
                            }
                        },
                        "services": {
                            "sysvinit": {
                                "httpd": {
                                    "enabled": "true",
                                    "ensureRunning": "true"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {"id": "0f900c9e-1272-4ec2-8a42-790b074baa39"}
            },
            "Properties": {
                "InstanceType": {"Ref": "InstanceType"},
                "ImageId": {
                    "Fn::FindInMap": [
                        "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                        {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                        {
                            "Fn::FindInMap": [
                                "AWSInstanceType2Arch",
                                {"Ref": "InstanceType"},
                                "Arch"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyName"},
                "NetworkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "GroupSet": [
                            {"Ref": "WebServerSecurityGroup"}
                        ],
                        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
                        "DeviceIndex": "0",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                        "SubnetId": {"Ref": "PublicSubnet"}
                    }
                ],
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                                "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
                                "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
                                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                                "         --stack ",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},
                                "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                                "         --configsets All ",
                                "         --region ",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                                "\n",
                                "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                                "         --stack ",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"},
                                "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
                                "         --region ",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                                "\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "CreationPolicy": {
                "ResourceSignal": {"Timeout": "PT5M"}
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "URL": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "http://",
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "WebServerInstance",
                                "PublicIp"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "Description": "Newly created application URL"
        },
        "SubnetCIDR": {
            "Value": {"Ref": "PublicSubnet"},
            "Description": "Subnet for the application"
        }
    },
    "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": -40,
                    "y": 210
                },
                "z": 1,
                "embeds": []
            },
            "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 250
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 70,
                    "y": 190
                },
                "z": 1,
                "embeds": [
                    "2e76192b-a4f8-48a5-92b6-abbfa8b83263",
                    "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d"
                ]
            },
            "2e76192b-a4f8-48a5-92b6-abbfa8b83263": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 280,
                    "y": 370
                },
                "z": 2,
                "parent": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee",
                "embeds": []
            },
            "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 120
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 90,
                    "y": 230
                },
                "z": 2,
                "parent": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee",
                "embeds": ["143bbaa1-66a2-42a5-885f-e6300817103c"]
            },
            "1790ebeb-2e41-4293-8cc1-aaba134fd1e0": {
                "source": {"id": "a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63"},
                "target": {"id": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee"},
                "z": 1
            },
            "143bbaa1-66a2-42a5-885f-e6300817103c": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 120,
                    "y": 260
                },
                "z": 3,
                "parent": "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d",
                "embeds": [],
                "references": ["a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63"],
                "dependson": ["1790ebeb-2e41-4293-8cc1-aaba134fd1e0"],
                "isrelatedto": ["a166c4f5-7cc4-429b-b9d8-2c8c43facc63"]
            },
            "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 120
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 250,
                    "y": 230
                },
                "z": 0,
                "embeds": ["0f900c9e-1272-4ec2-8a42-790b074baa39"]
            },
            "0f900c9e-1272-4ec2-8a42-790b074baa39": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 280,
                    "y": 260
                },
                "z": 3,
                "parent": "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3",
                "embeds": [],
                "isrelatedto": ["2e76192b-a4f8-48a5-92b6-abbfa8b83263"]
            },
            "13e0e0da-40c9-45d0-8460-7732ed20d764": {
                "source": {"id": "96a791f0-938b-4ebe-9f3c-b3fe2a588aee"},
                "target": {"id": "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3"},
                "z": 2
            },
            "528e2b71-46e6-4e09-815a-f70630755219": {
                "source": {"id": "175bad80-0988-4588-a919-331be705b02d"},
                "target": {"id": "3df467ad-673c-4c48-a41c-3ac1626961e3"},
                "z": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! It solves my problem perfectly!

Comment: @wander No problem. Glad it worked out:-)